# SWI-Prolog file executing through Java

Tags: java, command-line, prolog

I want to run SWI-Prolog from Java file. I want to read text.pl file and write the output in output.txt file. How can I do that? 
I'm not pretty sure of what I did here if it is correct or not. I'm not familiar with the command line calling.
This is the Java code:

```
public class Example
{
         public static void main(String[] args)
         {
            SystemCommandsRunner scr = new SystemCommandsRunner();
            scr.runCommand("swipl -f input.pl < input.pl > output.txt");
         }
}
```

Comment: Well, what does that code do? Does it work?

Comment: Is this `swipl` command a linux one, or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("swipl -f input.pl < input.pl > output.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/java_api/

I may suggest you to use this, it is a bidirectional API for prolog and java

I tried a long time ago, and it worked well